# How do I disassemble these AHF pedals?

Tags: maintenance, pedals, vintage

I am trying to disassemble a set of pedals to service them but I can't figure out what tool to use on the nut (see photo). I just need them temporarily until I can cycle to the bike co-op to change them, so if I can't get them apart, can I lubricate them somehow when they are still assembled so that they turn more easily? I have an aerosol grease I could just spray in.

Many thanks! Gill

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open end of a combination wrench should work on the square nut. An adjustable wrench should also work but you'd have to be careful to not round off the nut.

You cannot properly grease the bearings with the pedal assembled. You will not be able to spray grease or lubrication into the bearings.

Comment: I will give it a try. I already did once but I was concerned about rounding it off. Thank you!

Comment: That was the best possible outcome. The pedals came off the crank arm when I turned the nut. So I can just replace them as I can't get the apart anyway. Thank you.